# Efficient way of executing 1 million AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, loops, request

I want to call 1 million different URLs with AJAX.

What I did is (Javascript, jQuery used):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3...1000000]; // numbers.length = 1000000
$(function () {
    $.each(numbers, function(key, val) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getter.php',
            data: { id: val},
            success: function () {
                console.info(id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I loop over 1 million integers, and passing them to my getter.php (which is doing something cool with that numbers).

The problem is after ~1,5k of requests I get Google Chrome dead.

I know I do this ineffective way, that's why am asking for help - how to actually do it right? How to GET request a php script 1 million times (not necessary with JavaScript!)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a persistent connection between your php script and the client requesting the data.

I think you are bumping into a limitation of the time to live on the single request you are calling. Also the HTTP requests functions as a Request - Response why, when you put it in your foreach statement, each single statement is being processed alone like:

```
 1. iteration: GET /getter.php with value 1 .... wait... Oh theres a response
 2. iteration GET /getter.php with value 2 .... wait Oh another response
```

This is a seemingly long and wrong proces as you might already have figured out.

Another approach would be to set up a persistent socket, which functions like the TCP procotol:

```
 1. open the connection
 2. send all the data
 3. close the connection
```

Have you considered trying with a websocket?
Heres a few tutorials:
HTML5websocket
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

PHP socket:
http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

EDIT:
Also see this article on the difference between AJAX and websocket.

"AJAX is great if you aren’t in a hurry, but if you’re moving a high volume of data then the overhead of creating an HTTP connection every time is going to be a bottleneck. You need a persistent connection instead. In addition, AJAX always has to poll the server for data rather than receive it via push from the server. If you want speed and efficiency you need WebSockets."

http://blog.safe.com/2014/08/websockets-ajax-webhooks-comparison/